# How to enable CKAN 2.0 dataset ratings?

Tags: rating, ckan

How can I enable CKAN 2.0 dataset rating? I read official CKAN 2.0 documentation, but I could not find what I'm interested. I read somewhere on web that dataset rating support is built in since 1.0, and that is hidden since from 1.7, but it should be enabled in UI. Can you help me?

Comment: Where did you read that? Can you elaborate what this "rating" should be? The 5 star model of Tim Berners-Lee?

Comment: For example, if you visit http://datahub.io/api/rest/dataset/rkb-explorer-wiki and lookup for ratings_average and ratings_count, you will see what I'm want to implement. I know for Tim Berners-Lee 5 star, and I install it via ckanext-qa extension. It works. This link https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/661 contains a question similar to mine. Also, on http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.2/stats.html?highlight=rating there is an option 'Top-rated datasets', but how to implement that?

Comment: It seems that [the code is still around to create ratings](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/cee500acf60aff62627869f425e1b75abe5be7d2/ckan/logic/action/create.py#L825). So you can at least do this via the API. But I don't think you can enable this in the UI, but you could create your own template and use the API function to save the rating.